# Как в RoR доставать json

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails

Встречаю такой код: `render json: @statuses` Я хочу переменной назначить json, а не выходит. И какие есть другие способы вывода json? Подскажите, кто знает

Comment: `.to_json`, `.as_json` или даже https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails way - это gem
['jbuilder'](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder).

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/207623)

Comment: @Modus, название библиотеки [является](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2615/178988) ответом на вопрос.